# If $f\in C([a,b])$, $M=\max_{[a,b]}f$ and $ f\geq0$ then ${(\int_{a}^{b}f^n)}^{1/n} \rightarrow M$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

This is exercise 18 section 7.2 of Bartle and Sherbert's real analysis.

It suffices to show that
$(\int_{a}^{b}(\frac{f(x)}{M})^ndx)^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow 1$.

We know that
$0\leq \frac{f(x)}{M}< 1\Longrightarrow (\frac{f(x)}{M})^n\rightarrow 0 $ and we do have $0\leq \frac{f(x)}{M}< 1$ for every $x\in [a,b]\setminus \{c\}$ where $M:=f(c)$ ($c$ exists by the continuity of $f$ and the compactness of $[a,b]$). Therefore $\int_{a}^{b}(\frac{f(x)}{M})^ndx\rightarrow 0$....

Comment: Careful; that $< 1$ should be a $\leq 1$. Think of, say, a constant $f$.

Comment: Of course. I corrected that. Thanks

Comment: I don't see it yet, but I pointed it out because your argument doesn't follow through in that case.

Comment: ...no argument there. Just thinking out loud

Comment: Well, you say "we know that" and "therefore" but the assertions that follow are not correct. Also, you may want to rewrite the title (it fails for $a = 0, b = 1, f \equiv 1$ and $M$ is mentioned but not used).

Comment: what happens if the max is 0? i only say this because u divide by M, but it is still a case that needs to be covered

Comment: The integrals all vanish, hence converge to $M = 0$ nonetheless (I am not say the exercise itself is wrong!)

Comment: @ guidoar. (1) If $f=1$, $a=0$, $b=1$, the statement follows with $M=1$.  (2) $M$ is defined in the title and is used in my "thinking out loud".

Comment: @ guidoar. Thanks for your interest in my question. Looking forward for your hints

Comment: @Medo I meant that it was not used in the title. In the latter, you write $\sqrt[n]{\int_a^b f^n} \to 0$. If $a = 0, b= 1, f\equiv 1$, this means $1 \to 0$.

Comment: Yes. I edited that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, taking $\widetilde{f} := f/M$ if necessary - and noting that the case $M = 0$ holds beforehand - we may assume $M =1$. Note that since $(-)^n$ is monotone, the function $f^n$ attains a maximum precisely where $f$ does and hence it must be $M^n = 1$. Fix $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = 1$.

We know that

$$
M_n^n = \int_a^b f^n(t)dt \leq (b-a),
$$
so
$$
M_n = \left(\int_a^b f^n(t)dt\right)^{1/n} \leq \sqrt[n]{b-a}
$$
and taking limits we obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n \leq 1$.

Now fix $0 < \delta < 1$ and, by continuity, consider an interval $(c-\varepsilon/2,c+\varepsilon/2)$ where $f(z) \geq 1-\delta$, so that $f^n(z) \geq (1-\delta)^n$. Hence

$$
M_n^n = \int_a^b f^n(t)dt \geq \int_{c-\varepsilon}^{c+\varepsilon} f^n(t)dt \geq (1-\delta)^n\varepsilon
$$
and thus
$$
M_n \geq (1-\delta)\varepsilon^{1/n}.
$$

Taking limits, we see that $\lim_{n \to \infty}M_n \geq 1-\delta$ for all $\delta \in (0,1)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Of course, away from the point $c$ where  $M=f(c)$ the function $(f/M)^n$ vanishes and so does its integral. On a small enough neighbourhood of  $c$, the integral behaves like that of a constant. What I was worried about is how small that neighborhood can be. But you reminded me in your answer that the width of that neighbourhood will be of power $1/n$ and becomes $1$ in the limit.. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! I was stuck on that for a while too. Cheers.